# Как сделать изменение клавиатуры на стрелки вперед/назад Aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет, возник вопрос. Есть сообщение, внизу его кнопки, созданные из массива с элементами 1-10 и ниже две стрелочки, отображаются только 1-5 на кнопках. Как сделать, чтобы при кнопке вперед отображалось, 6-10 и обратно также. Как можно это сделать через Inline клавиатуру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого необходима паганация, рекомендую aiogram-dialog

Так же можно создать две клавиатуры и при нажатии на кнопку "Вперед" менять клавиатуру с помощью

```
  message.edit_reply_markup(keyboard)
```

Вот пример

```
   @dp.callback_query(Text('call_data'))
   async def keyboards(call: types.CallbackQuery):
       await call.message.answer('text',   reply_markup=markup)


  @dp.callback_query(Text('next'))
  async def up_balance(call: types.CallbackQuery):
      await call.message.edit_reply_markup(markup)
```

Это на примере aiogram v.3.0.0b6
В первом хендлере вызывается первая клавиатура
Во втором при нажатии на кнопку "Вперед" с callback_data='next'

клавиатура меняется на вторую

Comment: А именно сам алгоритм, смены, тип шаг 5 получается просто и всё? @Trafalgar

Comment: Добавил пример в ответ